# Вызов конструктора при создании массива объектов

Tags: c#

Итак, C#...

```
MyClass h = new MyClass(); // так конструктор вызывается
MyClass []h = new MyClass[5]; // а так уже нет
```

Как правильно объявить массив объектов, чтоб для каждого элемента вызвался конструктор?
В C++ аналогичная конструкция работает как надо, и конструктор вызывается.

Comment: В C++ работают такие варианты: MyClass array[5]; MyClass *array=new Myclass[5]; И в обоих случаях конструкторы вызываются для каждого элемента. То, что можно вручную принициализировать в цикле - это и так знаю. Неужели в C#, при такой развитости, нет готового механизма инициализации объектов при создании массива?

Comment: можно заменить класс на структуру

Comment: @Grundy можно, только она будет инициализироваться дефолтными значениями типов, иначе говоря нулями и null-значениями. Так что все равно придется пробегать по массиву и инициировать внутреннюю логику, если она есть.

Comment: В С++ в обоих приведенных вами случаях объекты размещаются в самом массиве. В C# объекты ссылочных типов размещаются в куче, а в массиве будут только ссылки на них. Поэтому массив инициализируется при создании, но не объектами класса, что невозможно, а ссылками, разумеется пустыми. Считайте, что вы создаете не массив объектов, а массив указателей, и все встанет на свои места.

Comment: @rdorn, забавно, что хотели добавить возможность объявлять конструктор без параметров для структур, но передумали :)

Comment: @Grundy да уж, в отдельных случаях было бы полезно, вопрос какие побочные эффекты могут вылезти

Answer (score 4):

```
MyClass h = new MyClass(); // так конструктор вызывается
```

Тут вы создаете сам **объект класса** `MyClass`

```
MyClass []h = new MyClass[5]; // а так уже нет
```

А тут вы создаете **массив ссылок на объекты класса** `MyClass`

Что бы создать **массив объектов класса** `MyClass` вам требуется создать каждый объект собственноручно:

```
MyClass []h = new MyClass[5];
for (int i = 0; i < h.Length; i++) 
{
    h[i] = new MyClass();
}
```

Comment: более строго не "массив класса MyClass", а массив ссылок на объекты  MyClass. Поэтому и требуется ручное создание объектов. В cpp при тех же условиях будет создан массив объектов, т.е. в ячейках массива будут храниться сами объекты.

Comment: @rdorn благодарю за правку.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Массив - это отдельный объект. То есть грубо говоря мы создаем не "Пять объектов типа MyClass". А: "Один объект, размером в пять объектов MyClass". Как следствие создавать объекты при конструировании массива нельзя. Но объекты можно создавать после создания массива, Например в инициализаторе:

```
 MyClass[] mas =
            {
                new MyClass(),
                new MyClass(),
                new MyClass(),
                new MyClass(),
                new MyClass()
            };
```

Либо через "for" (как в соседнем ответе).

Comment: "Один объект, размером в пять объектов MyClass" в корне не верно, если MyClass не является структурой. Размер массива для ссылочных типов не зависит от размера объектов и не содержит самих объектов.

Comment: @rdorn ```если MyClass не является структурой``` есть подозрение, что не является :)

Comment: @tym32167 подозрение у меня тоже есть, но подозрение это только подозрение =)

Answer (score 0):

[Ответ AGS17](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676758/182750) жизнеспособен, но можно также воспользоваться и обобщенным методом:

```cs
T[] InitializeArray<T>(int length) where T : new() {

    T[] array = new T[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        array[i] = new T();
    }

    return array;
}
```

Использовать можно так:

```cs
MyClass[] h = InitializeArray<MyClass>(5);
```

Ответ взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301750/3129992).

Comment: В чем профит использования этого метода? Экономия 2 строчек кода? Он же (метод) сделает код чуточку медленней (или заинлайнится?), требует чуточку памяти (что не критично), и делает код чуточку менее понятней (читателю надо будет пройти и поглядеть, что же там происходит внутри метода), ещё и название метода не совсем верное, так как тут не только инициализация массива, но и элементов. Метод ещё и работает только с типами с дефолтным конструктором. По мне так  вещь бесполезная.

Comment: Этот метод при активном использовании будет работать значительно медленнее, чем при использовании цикла - new T() в генериках разворачивается в рефлекшн, Activator.CreateInstance, который значительно медленнее обычного new.

Comment: @PashaPash, тут уже был вопрос и обходной путь для этого :-)

Answer (score 0):

Эта тема обсуждалась здесь [How to declare an array of objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113115/c-is-there-a-linq-way-to-create-an-array-of-objects-given-an-array-of-construc).
Рекомендую использовать подобную запись:

```
MyClass[] arr = new MyClass[5];
arr = arr.Select(x => new MyClass()).ToArray();
```