# Конструктор массива структур с параметрами

Tags: c#, массивы, структуры

Здравствуйте. Имеется следующая структура:

```
public struct WiFiPointData_t
{
    public byte[] bssid;
    public sbyte rssi;

    public WiFiPointData_t(byte bssidSize)
    {
        bssid = new byte[bssidSize];
        rssi = 0;
    }
}
```

Нужно создать и проинициализировать массив данной структуры через конструктор с параметрами. Ни один из следующих вариантов не работает (получаем ошибку):

```
WiFiPointData_t[] wifiPointsTemp = new WiFiPointData_t(BSSID_SIZE)[MAX_WLAN_ENTRIES]; 
WiFiPointData_t[] wifiPointsTemp = new WiFiPointData_t[MAX_WLAN_ENTRIES](BSSID_SIZE);
```

Вариант инициализации в цикле работоспособен, но хотелось бы более простое и элегантное решение. Подскажите, как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вызов конструктора при создании массива объектов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676755/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: @Grundy, со структурами нужно быть аккуратнее, чтобы не создавать их по два раза - первый раз с конструктором по умолчанию, второй раз с нужным конструктором

Comment: @Андрей, ну конструктор по умолчанию, если его можно так назвать, весьма легок у структур. В любом случае что-то будет делаться два раза

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ещё один вариант:

```
Enumerable.Repeat(new WiFiPointData_t(BSSID_SIZE), MAX_WLAN_ENTRIES).ToArray()
```

---

Заметьте, что этот вариант хорош потому, что `WiFiPointData_t` — `struct`, а значит, в массиве будут *копии* начального экземпляра. Для класса в массиве были бы ссылки на один и тот же экземпляр.

Comment: Надо упомянуть, что если `WiFiPointData_t` не структура, а класс - этот вариант использовать нельзя! (ну или надо понимать, что будет массив, содержащий один и тот же объект)

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Угу, в вопросе упоминается именно `struct`. Напишу замечание, да.

Answer (score 3):

К счастью, у нас есть Linq, воспользуемся им:

```
WiFiPointData_t[] wifiPointsTemp
    = Enumerable.Range(0, MAX_WLAN_ENTRIES)
                .Select(x => new WiFiPointData_t(BSSID_SIZE))
                .ToArray();
```

или так:

```
WiFiPointData_t[] wifiPointsTemp
    = new int[MAX_WLAN_ENTRIES]
        .Select(x => new WiFiPointData_t(BSSID_SIZE))
        .ToArray();
```

Этот способ подойдет также для любых классов, в том числе не имеющих конструктора по умолчанию